# Append Image or content to an existing PDF with PDFSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

Is it possible to append to the end of an existing PDF file with PDFsharp?

I want to embed one or more of the following content types:

- HTML
- PNG (or other image formats)
- TIFF

Comment: Thanks Glenn for Editing my question and make it more sensible

Answer (score 0):

With PDFsharp you can append pages and add various image formats to those new pages.

You cannot add HTML directly. On NuGet you can find a project "HTML Renderer for PDF using PdfSharp" for that purpose.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, by any chance do we have any sample code for conversion  PNG,JPEG,TIFF in to PDF ?

Comment: @DevDevloper Look at the Graphics sample on this site: http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpSamples.ashx The PDFsharp source package includes the complete source for all samples.

Comment: Hello Thomas, I looked at that graphics class I have developed below code.   using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                byte[] imagepdfbytes = null;
                PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
                doc.Pages.Add(new PdfPage());
                XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[0]);
                XImage img = XImage.FromFile(fileUrl);
                xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
                doc.Save(outStream, true);
                imagepdfbytes = outStream.ToArray();
                return imagepdfbytes;
            }

Comment: but with above code at line  XImage img = XImage.FromFile(fileUrl); i get out of memory exception

Comment: @DevDevloper You need an image file in the local file system. The name "fileUrl" suggest you're trying "http://" or something like that. That will not work. Download the file from the web into a stream and pass the stream to XImage.

Comment: forgot to mention File URL is not an http:// , its a physical path where Image exists  that is local file system path for example

Comment: @DevDevloper There is nothing I can do without the image. You can try a different PDFsharp version (WPF instead of GDI+ or vice versa), try a newer version (1.50 beta from NuGet) or an older version (1.30 from CodePlex). I assume you tried 1.32. Or provide the image file so we can test it.

Comment: @PDFsharpTeam  : I was able to figure that out , but now the image is cutting of the PDF page , can you suggest me the code change to make that pdf  come in center of the page and along with image user uploads a pdf when i try to put that pdf i get this  error 
"Cannot handle iref streams. The current implementation of PDFsharp cannot handle this PDF feature introduced with Acrobat 6." Do we have anything to resolve this ?